# Node's background image is clipped when using border

Tags: css, cytoscape.js

I want to use PNG (or SVG) background-image (background-fit : 'contain') and then dynamically change node border (based on data). Everything works except one thing: node border is rendered "centered" around the node, so half of the line is outside the node's dimensions and half is inside the node. This clips the background image (see nodes.jpg below).

[nodes.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49t8u.jpg)

As a workaround I tried to use 'background-width' and 'background-height' (set to 60%) to create something like padding in CSS but this changes the aspect ratio of the background image (it stretched the image) which I don't want.

Is there a way how to achieve the desired result with the current CSS styles in Cytoscape.js (I'm using CY 2.7.11)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the way a stroke works in a canvas.  Unless browsers add new API to control stroke position (inside, outside, on/mid), there's no performant way to have outer borders.

Set a padding to enlarge the outer width/height of the node without affecting its inner width/height (used for bg img sizing): http://js.cytoscape.org/#style/node-body

Just set a padding to half the border width or greater.

Comment: I tried set 'padding' before and it didn't worked so I focused on 'background-clip', 'background-fit' etc. After your suggestion to use 'padding' I played a little more with it and figured out that 'padding' is not working but 'padding-top', 'padding-left', 'padding-bottom', 'padding-right' works. Maybe it should be mentioned in the docs explicitly (or it's a bug?). Anyway, my problem is solved (although I have to dynamically calculate also the 'text-margin-x' and 'text-margin-y' in order to not overlap borders and labels), thanks!

Comment: If you can use padding-* instead of padding, you're using <2.7.13.  Unequal paddings make edge placement not possible in many cases (among other problems).  It was a design error.  The fix was to enforce the same value on all sides.  For compatibility, the old padding-* props work on new versions.  The last value you specify is used for the proper padding prop.  https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues/1638